# Is it possible do connect in Bluemix MySql from my dev machine like I can with Google Cloud?

Tags: mysql, ibm-cloud

I created a **MySQL** database in **IBM Bluemix** and bound it to my app.

I can see its credentials but couldn't find a way to create table in the web interface of **Bluemix**.

So this is the credentials I have:

```
{
  "mysql-5.5": [
    {
      "name": "mysql-AspNet5App",
      "label": "mysql-5.5",
      "plan": "100",
      "credentials": {
        "name": "MoreText",
        "hostname": "SomeIp",
        "host": "SomeIp",
        "port": SomePort,
        "user": "SomeUser",
        "username": "SomeUser",
        "password": "password",
        "uri": "mysql://SomeText@SomeIp:SomePort/MoreText"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I interact with this database directly (without the app linked to it) by using a problem like **Workbench** or at least a Web Interface?

I tried to connect with those credential but **Workbench** said:

> Your connection attempt failed for user 'SomeUser' from your host to
>   server at SomeIp:SomePort:   Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'SomeIp' (10060)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only access MySQL service from Bluemix applications. MySQL service is just an experimental service for you to test Bluemix applications and it does not provide a web interface.

However you can use PHPMyAdmin as an alternative web interface to create tables, run queries, etc in your Bluemix MySQL service instance.

You just have to create an application in Bluemix with PHPMyAdmin and bind your MySQL service instance to it. Fortunately someone already wrote that application and made it available in GitHub.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/dmikusa-pivotal/cf-ex-phpmyadmin.git
```

Update the `manifest.yml` file to fit your application name and MySQL service instance, for example:

```
---
applications:
- name: my-phpmyadmin
  memory: 128M
  disk_quota: 1024M 
  instances: 1
  host: my-phpmyadm
  domain: mybluemix.net
  path: .
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git#8c13f5434b2f31ca960d2bca9153df1978258535
  services:
  - mysql-AspNet5App
```

Push the application to Bluemix:

```
$ cf push
```

You can then access your application from:

http://my-phpadmin.mybluemix.net

To login use the `username` and `password` from your MySQL service credentials.

PS: Alternatively you can use ClearDB MySQL service in Bluemix as well. It offers a free plan and can be accessed externally using Workbench.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up getting the easier ClearDB solution you provided (since I'm just testing for now) and it just worked.

Comment: A bit of OFF TOPIC but do you know if the MySQL service from Bluemix will have direct connection available in the future?

Comment: No Victor, I don't know the answer to that.